# system crash while using dual operating system

Tags: boot

I'm using windows 7 i installed Ubuntu as second operating system.
My windows files are shows in Ubuntu but i cant able to open it,after some weeks my system has crash windows is not booting.

My question is dual operating system with windows and Ubuntu is good?
If it is good how to install it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Ubuntu in dual-boot with Windows, the best way for a beginning user is:

- Install Windows on a partition using 40% of your hard disk
- Install Ubuntu on a partition using 40% of your hard disk
- create a FAT32 partition of 10% of your hard disk
- Leave the other 10% space free for now to allocate it later to wherever you will need it.

Then:

- When you use Windows, use your Windows applications on your Windows files
- When you use Ubuntu, use your Ubuntu Applications on your Ubuntu files.
- When you need files accessible to both Ubuntu and Windows, store them on the FAT partition.

**Never any problems!**